# Indexing VARCHAR in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-performance, sqldatatypes

Is performance of index on a VARCHAR field compared to INT field same or worse?

I have a table with two fields(Both are of VARCHAR). I want to create an index on 1st column. I have two things in my mind.
1. Directly create index on first field.
2. Assign an integer to each VARCHAR in the first field and store them in a table. Then replace the VARCHARs in the first column with integers and create another table and index on the first colum(In this case it will be integer column). I will end up with two different tables here.

Also if I have 4 or 5 tables with same 1st field and have to create index on the 1st field in every table, will the second method give better performance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long are your texts? And: how do you access the values? Do you look/search for the text? Do you ever want to sort the data in the table by the text value?

Comment: Each entry will be around 8 characters. I Just  want to search second field using 1st field entry. No need of sorting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indexes on `VARCHAR()` columns are indeed slightly less efficient than indexes on fixed-length fields like `INT` or `BIGINT`. But not significantly so.

The *only conceivable situation* where you would want to use a second table containing a numbered list of text strings is this: the number of distinct text strings in your application is much smaller than the number of rows in your tables.   Why might that be true?  For example, the text strings might be words in a so-called ["controlled vocabulary."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_vocabulary)  For example, music tracks have a genre like "rock", "classical", or "hiphop".  It's pointless to allow arbitrary genres like "southern california alt-surf-rock" in such an application.

Don't overthink this. Keep in mind that database server developers have spent a great deal of time optimizing the performance of their indexes. It's almost impossible that you can do better than they have done, especially if you have to introduce extra tables and constraints to your system.

Put indexes on your `VARCHAR()` columns as needed.

(Another factor: collations get baked into indexes on `VARCHAR()` columns. If you build a custom indexing scheme like the one you propose, you have to deal with that complexity in your code. It's a notorious pain in the neck.)

Fun fact to know and tell: Systems in the olden days of computing (when all the cool kids had T1 lines) offered objects called "atoms." These were text strings referred to with id numbers.  Atoms showed up in the X Window System (for example) in the [xlib function call `XInternAtom()` and related functions](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xinternatom).   Why? partly to save memory and network bandwidth, which were scarcer then than now. Partly for the "controlled vocabulary" purpose mentioned earlier in this post.

Comment: +1 also useful to move text strings to a lookup table if you want to be able to change a string in one place and have many rows that reference it use the new value without possibility of anomalies. This is close to the same thing as you were saying.

Answer (score 2):

The difference in performance of an index on varchar vs. an index on int is small enough to be irrelevant, unless you get into large scale (e.g. on the order of hundreds of millions of rows).

My advice is to keep your design simple and straightforward. Just run searches on the indexed varchar.

If you reach a scale where you think this is a bottleneck, then consider redesigning at that time.

Comment: exactly. Get your app working. If it scales up then you can solve a performance problem.